# Python hmac in c#

Tags: python, c#

This is the python code which I have to convert in c#

```
   ms = "ninoingfbf"
    key = "AgQGCAoMDhASFA=="
    h = hmac.new(key.encode('utf-8'), ms.encode('utf-8'),
     hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().lower()
    print( h )
```

I was trying the below c# code, but I am getting different results

```
 string msg = "ninoingfbf";
  string keystring = "AgQGCAoMDhASFA==";
  byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(keystring);
  HMACSHA256 hmac = new(key);
  byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));
  var j = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
   return Ok(j);
```

Python output =  "10d46c65b51ddbb1f3346dca71ca30f139a473dece78dc567f404fdc4ee49e51"

c# output =  "2980906b9e1933357db6fc6b791d2d43564555a949667cc9525eff037466add0"

Comment: The two snippets *don't* do the same thing. The Python code *doesn't* decode the BASE64 key. The Python code needs to be fixed, eg `hmac.new(base64.b64decode(key),ms.encode(),hashlib.sha256)`. In Python 3 the default is `utf-8` already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python code is wrong. It doesn't decode the BASE64 key but uses it as if it was the actual key. The key must be decoded using the `base64` library, not encoded as UTF-8.

Strings in Python3 are Unicode and the default encoding is `utf-8`, so there's no need to explicitly specify it.

The following code returns the same hash as the C# code:

```
import base64
import hash
import hashlib

ms = "ninoingfbf"
key = "AgQGCAoMDhASFA=="

h=hmac.new(base64.b64decode(key),ms.encode(),hashlib.sha256)

print (h.hexdigest())
```

This returns

```
2980906b9e1933357db6fc6b791d2d43564555a949667cc9525eff037466add0
```

Which is identical to the C# output

```
2980906b9e1933357db6fc6b791d2d43564555a949667cc9525eff037466add0
```

.NET 5 added a [Convert.ToHexString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tohexstring?view=net-6.0) method, so the C# code becomes:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

var msg = "ninoingfbf";
var key = "AgQGCAoMDhASFA==";

HMACSHA256 hmac = new(Convert.FromBase64String(key));
var h = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(h).ToLower());
```

If you want to save the hash text for comparison you can get rid of `ToLower()` and use a case-insensitive comparison. In C# you can use one of the [String.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-6.0#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) overloads that ignores case, eg :

```
var areEqual=String.Compare(hash1,hash2,true);
```

Comment: @mof the Python code is wrong. It's as simple as that. If you try to use that borked hash, you won't be able to match it with any other tool, no matter what language it's written in. If you try to use a commandline tool to calculate the hash of a file, you'll get the hash returned by C#, not the one returned by the buggy Python code

Comment: @mof of course, if you insist on not fixing that code, you can use the BASE64 string without decoding it with `HMACSHA256 hmac = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));` You'll keep getting into trouble as every system or application will complain the hash is wrong. That includes the API you're probably trying to connect to

Comment: thanks solved,i actually need to make c# like python code from a other system, from a other company,  so i change my C# code to   byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keystring); and its working now